# How would you say " If you'd like to speak English, it's fine by me"?

Tags: translation, usage

The concept would be like, a Japanese asks you if you are OK with speaking English with him and you want to answer back " If you'd like to speak English (instead of Japanese), it's fine by me". I'm looking for something more complex than " 英語で話してもいいです". Maybe a formation with ば ?

Comment: I specified in the explanatory comment above I'm looking for something more complex than mo ii desu. I'm looking to say " If you want to speak X, that's fine by me" not " It is OK to speak X". Are there any alternative ways, more formal, more "literate" e.t.c.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am flailing around as I don't think I fully understand what you are seeking after...

I would say 「英語で話して頂いても構いませんよ」to convey the meaning of "If you'd like to speak English (instead of Japanese), it's fine by me."